# Is using like '%' the same as saying "IS NOT NULL"?

Tags: sql, oracle

If not, why would somebody use abc like '%' ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm

Answer (score 4):

Just test it?

```
  drop table junk;

  create table junk ( id  number, col  varchar2(10) );

  insert into junk values ( 123, null );
  insert into junk values ( 234, ' ' );
  insert into junk values ( 345, 'asdf' );

  commit;

  select *
    from junk
   where col like '%'
  /

          ID COL
  ---------- ----------
         234
         345 asdf
```

So no, as with most things Oracle, direct compares won't see NULL ... If you want to detect for NULL, use IS NULL.  If you want to exclude NULLs, be clear, and include IS NOT NULL .. (even if something like this "looks like" it eliminates it) ;)  By using "IS NOT NULL" it'll be much clearer to anyone reading the code.

Relevant links:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52142

A percent sign (%) in the pattern can match zero or more characters (as opposed to bytes in a multibyte character set) in the value. **The pattern '%' cannot match a null.**

Comment: Testing this in a large table (over a million rows) you can also see that doing a `LIKE '%'` operation is also much less performant. They may coincidentally be functionally equivalent, but the cost is much higher doing unnecessary text comparisons.

Comment: @HepC: Agreed - which is why I indicated he should use IS NOT NULL to check instead of '%' ;)

Comment: thanks guys, that's what I figured, but I had a test case that was telling me that the like % was performing better than the is not null, so just wanted to see if there was something I was missing....thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Effectively, yes. I've seen it used when people want to pass in a like condition parameter, so that they can pass in a specific value, a partial value or no value into a query that's of the form `select ... from ... where some_col like :some_parameter`.

ETA: I would point out that if I saw `where some_col like '%'` in production code when the person who wrote it really meant `where some_col is not null` I think I'd have plenty of words to say to them! The latter condition is much more self-descriptive and clear in its intent, and won't leave people scratching their heads wondering what the person was thinking of when they wrote it!